# Cannot copy struct's items into another struct

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I have struct `Node` and struct `UniqueInstructor`. Both are singly-linked lists. I have already filled struct Node with some values. Now what I need to do is fill the second UniqueInstructor struct with Node's struct specific value (`std::string instructor`).

This is how my structs look like:

```
// main struct that I already filled with data

struct Node {
    Node* pNext;
    std::string data1;
    std::string data2;
    std::string day;
    std::string group;
    std::string instructor; // these are the items I want to copy
                            // into the UniqueInstructor struct
    std::string course;
};

// my 'target' struct, also linked list

struct UniqueInstructor {
    UniqueInstructor* pNext;
    std::string instructor;
};
```

For now, all I need to do is copy all the `std::string instructor` values from `Node` into `UniqueInstructor`.

I have tried bunch of things, such as:

```
void DuplicateInstructor(Node *&pHead)
{
    pHead = new UniqueInstructor { pHead, pHead->instructor };
}
```

but I am getting errors. In this case:
`cannot convert 'Node*' to 'UniqueInstructor*' in initialization`

My problem probably lies somewhere in passing struct into that function. Please be forgiving, I am fresh-new to structs and pointers. Thank you for help.

Comment: Why should that assignment work? The types don't match.

Comment: @SidS You mean `UniqueInstructor*`?

Comment: You're trying to assign a `Node *` to a `UniqueInstructor *` and vice versa. Why do you think that should work ?

Comment: If I do void `DuplicateInstructor(UniqueInstructor *&pHead)` instead, then I cannot see how this function can be related with `Node` struct. Also getting an error inside main when trying to execute this function with `UniqueInstructor *instructorptr = nullptr;
        Duplicate(instructorptr);`. Error: `invalid initialization of reference of type 'Node*&' from expression of type 'UniqueInstructor*'`

Comment: It appears as though you might be wanting inheritance here.

Comment: I don't know anything about OOP, this seems advanced stuff, is there a simplier way?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy the `Node::instructor` field into the `UniqueInstructor::instructor` field. Both fields are `std::string` so that is no problem.

```
void like_this(Node& n, UniqueInstructor& i)
{
    i.instructor = n.instructor;
}
```

Now it's not very clear what you actually trying to achieve and what your program structure is so I can't tell you where or how you get the `Instructor` object. In the example above both objects exist. Also you can't link a `Node` with an `UniqueInstructor`. Simply `Node::pNext` and `UniqueInstructor::pNext` are of completely different types, so I don't know what you are trying to do here.

Moreover explicit `new` / `delete` calls are a very bad practice. They have absolutely no place in C++ (outside of library implementations). Too much headache and more importantly too much room for bugs (memory leaks on exceptions). Please read about RAII and smart pointers in C++.